# can't start Tomcat Server in eclipse(windows)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

```
Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:941)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 你的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 29 more

十二月 20, 2016 9:55:48 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
严重: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:941)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 你的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 29 more

十二月 20, 2016 9:55:48 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
十二月 20, 2016 9:55:48 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
严重: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:941)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 你的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 28 more

十二月 20, 2016 9:55:48 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
严重: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:941)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 你的主机中的软件中止了一个已建立的连接。
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 28 more
```

everytime i start my tomcat server,eclipse encounter that error.
and i have searched many times,the most results is :

1. 8080 port has been used
2. less results like `["http-nio-8080"]`,most are `http-bio-8080`,`http-apr-8080` etc.
3. `web.xml` file has a wrong config
4. restart or reinstall tomcat,eclipse,computer
   i have try all things ,but nothing is help.And i search on stackoverflow ,no sultion is help.

Comment: If possible, set your language / locale to *en_US* and collect the error messages once more so that they contain more meaningful descriptions. For example, if you are running Linux / BSD / etc, invoke Eclipse in the following way: `env LC_MESSAGES=en_US eclipse`.

Comment: most useful chinese info means :The software in your host aborted an established connection.

Comment: `Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]` . Change the AJP port if 8009 is not available

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you change Tomcat to use another port. To do this, open your server.xml file (in C:\Tomcat 8.0\conf). There should be a Connector element in here with an attribute port="8080": change this port number to 8081 (say) and restart Tomcat.

Comment: and i download a zip file from apache ,not setup file